# FOSS PDF Reader on Linux with PDFium

Tags: linux, pdf, open-source, reader

Using Linux for a year, I have found that some PDFs could not be rendered correctly by Evince; sometimes Evince could not function properly when the PDF file has many pages(slow to load & wait)

So I want to find some FOSS PDF Readers on Linux, built with other library rather than the one Evince uses, such as PDFium/PDF.js.(I do not want to use Browser as a PDF Reader).

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://pdfreaders.org/.

PDFium and PDF.js are Javascript solutions that need a browser, so you can't have one without the other.

I'm using Okular. It uses the same library as Evince (called poppler) but a different backend, so rendering is different for certain PDFs.

You could also try mupdf which has a completely different rendering engine.